# "Visit Meta" section

Tags: discussion

I'm curious about the "Visit Meta" section on the main page. What are the criteria for a question landing there? Many of the questions (at least as far as I can tell) are older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the criteria is that if the question is tagged `[featured]` then it will appear.

There are others, but I can't find the original MSO post that explains them right now, but they are related to the activity on the question.

Comment: Can anyone tag a question [featured]?

Comment: @Michael - only moderators (those with the ♦ after their name) can use the red tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's built based on "hot" meta question lists, plus the [featured] tag.

Click here to see what it uses:

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=week
https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot

... in that order

The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is problematic because users tend to leave the featured tag on.. *forever*. Which I disagree with, so we'll be pushing some changes on that soon.